# Css background color with submenu

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<ul>
  <li class="main"> Main 1
    <ul>
      <li class="sub">Sub 1</li>
      <li class="sub">Sub 2</li>
      <li class="sub">Sub 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main"> Main 2 </li>
  <li class="main">Main 3 </li>  
</ul>
```

I want the `background-color` of the first level change on mouse over. But when I try this code

```
.main:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.sub:hover {
  background-color: none;
}
```

The sublevel menu also gets changed. Is there a way to change only the background of the outside element.

This code can be seen in action in this codepen.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bvauf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is the background of `.main`, because the children's backgrounds are transparent. You could explicitly set it to white:

```
.main:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.main:hover > ul {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Or

```
.main ul {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thanks that's it. Now makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
.sub {
  background-color: white;
}
```

You should go with setting background colors to ul and not li as others have suggested